# Unable to run ethers.getSigner() from the (nodeJS?) console

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am following a Hardhat intro tutorial by **Reanblock** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osHk0eEsjDM and I am stuck in the last few minutes of the video.

I have a simple `hardhat.config.js` file as follows:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-web3"); 
require('solidity-coverage');

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

task("azbalance", "-prints a/c balances- ")
  .addParam("azaccount", "the accounts address")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs) => {
    const account = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(taskArgs.azaccount);
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"), "ETH");
  })


/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

I successfully created a node in another terminal using the command:

```
npx hardhat node
```

I am able to deploy the contract using the following command.

```
npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network localhost
```

on the console I type:

```
npx hardhat console --network localhost
```

so far it has been working as expected.

on the (NodeJS ? ) console when I type

```
acc = await ethers.getSigner()
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ethers.getSigner is not a function
    at REPL1:1:47
```

my goal is to get the account address using the command:

```
acc.address
```

**** Apologies if used the terms Terminal and Console incorrectly. I'm yet to figure out its proper usage ***

Answer (score 1):

Where do you run the command `npx hardhat console --network localhost`?

- Make sure you run from the folder contained the `hardhat.config.js` file.
- Please try with the simple config first:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  defaultNetwork: "localhost",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
    }
  }
};
```

- You should able to achieve

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your @PySol. I cleared my `hardhat.config.js` file and copied your code in it, closed all open terminals and opened a new terminal and ran the `npx hardhat console --network localhost` 

To your 1st bullet point, I don't know how to run a command from a particular folder. The `Hardhat.config.js` was open while I ran command. 

When I just type `>ethers ` in the console, I get a large dump which looks like its in a JSON format.  It does not have a `getSigner` function defined. there is only a `getSigners: [AsyncFunction: getSigners]` .  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: given you have `getSigners` but `getSigner`. It seems there's a version issue, please check the version of your hardhat (npx). And checkout the doc for that version.